# How to speed up PK and index creation on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Creation of a PK and index on 880 mio rows takes about 1:15 hrs.

Query:

```
 alter table STG.NOTES add constraint PK_NOTES primary key (NOTES_SK);
 create unique index STG.BK_NOTES on STG.NOTES (NOTE_NBR ASC);
```

Is there a way to speed this up? I read of parallel and nologging options. The Oracle Server has 2 CPUs, so parallel (n-1 = 2-1 = 1) wont help. Leaving only nologging. What can you tell me about it? What is the trade off? Why would/wouldn't you use it?

edit:
maybe I also need to explain what the context of index creation is:

1. truncate target table, then drop PK and index on target table
2. select from source and bulk insert into target
3. create index and PK on target table (= 1:15 hrs)

Comment: Have you tried leaving the indexes in place while you load the data? While this'll make the insert take longer, it may be quicker overall than drop, insert and recreate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use a higher degree of parallelism on a pc with 2 cores. check the `parallel_max_servers` for the default setting in you db.

`show parameter parallel_max_servers`

To perform in parallel you can use

`alter session force parllel ddl parallel 4`

8 slaved will be created in addition to the coordinator.

About `nologging`,I think it's a good option. using `nologging` means that in the event of a disaster you'll have to recreate your indexes. If the index creation process is a routine, you can consider it.

Comment: show parameter parallel_max_servers
>Show parameters query failed
, any idea? maybe missing permission to read parameters?

Comment: could be. try executing in parallel anyway. you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/parallel002.htm#BEICCFIE) about the default limit. you should be fine with degree of 4.

Comment: @BaseBallBatBoy In case you didn't know, `show parameter ...` will only work in SQL*Plus.  In most other environments you'll need to run something like `select value from v$parameter where name = 'parallel_max_servers';`.  Also, I agree with haki, try building it in parallel.  There are a lot of myths surrounding the degree of parallelism, you'll definitely want to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**[NOSORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF54002)** If `NOTE_NBR` is already ordered you can save time
by not sorting the data.  This may be true if NOTE_NBR is created from a single-threaded sequence or if your query is ordered.

**Don't re-gather index statistics** Creating or rebuilding indexes automatically creates the index statistics.  If you re-gather statistics on the
table, `cascade=>false` can save some time.  The default option, `cascade=>dbms_stats.auto_cascade` [does not really work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12226/does-dbms-stats-auto-cascade-ever-work).